# Using web service in class library which is referenced in the website project of same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services

How to access proxy class of a web service which has been referenced in the website project of a solution within a class library project in the same solution?

I mean no web-service reference/setting is added to the class library and instead it needs to be picked from the web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very bad approach.
Two possible options:
- create the proxy class in your class library project; reference that class library in your project
- create proxy in 3rd class library project that will be references all across your solution.

Comment: Bad as in? Does that mean each project should have individual, personalized web references for the services being used?

Comment: No, every project will use the same reference. For example, you can have one CL Services in which you can reference every service that you want to use in your solution.